# Android Chrome occasionally not showing select text on popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, bootstrap-5

I'm writing a website and when I use it on my android phone in chrome, I SOME TIMES don't see the text on the select pop up. It's not every time, but it's enough to notice it happening.

I don't typically notice it on other people's sites so I think it's me.

I have a feeling it has to do with me populating the html after the dom has rendered (data from ajax request).

The markup looks like a standard select from bootstrap.

I'm using jquery to set the html. It just a normal select, I'm not using any library to convert it or otherwise manipulate it.

Has anyone else ever seen this behavior? What's the fix?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77810059/edit) to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you're having.